# Update tabla sql

Tags: mysql

Tengo que hacer "update" en tabla formulario y tengo que seleccionar el valor "id_proceso" de la tabla propietario_procesos.
En la tabla formulario el id_proceso ahora es = 0 pero quiero coger el id_proceso de la tabla propietario_procesos. En esta tabla el id_proceso=3. 
¿Como quedaría la sentencia sql?

[image: Tabla formulario]

[image: Tabla propietario_procesos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendiendo que tienes dos tablas:

- Tabla Formulario :

  - id, mensaje, tipo_formulario, fecha, id_proceso
- Tabla Propietario_procesos:

  - id_proceso, nombre_propietario.

Entiendo, que lo que quieres hacer, es actualizar una fila en la tabla "formulario", en base a datos de la tabla "propietario_procesos". Corrígeme si me equivoco.
Hablas de id_propietario y no lo veo en la definición, por lo que entiendo que será una columna de la tabla "propietario_procesos".
Con la información que facilitas, si quisieras obtener los id de los formularios sobre los que ha ejecutado algún proceso un id de propietario(en este caso 3), sería:

```
SELECT distinct(id) #Si se ha ejecutado mas de un proceso en un formulario, no saldrá el id repetido.
FROM formulario
WHERE id_proceso IN (SELECT id_proceso
                    FROM propietario_procesos
                    WHERE id_propietario = 3)
```

Y si por ejemplo, quisieras actualizar la fecha de un proceso en concreto en base a un propietario, tendrías que obtener primero el id del proceso:

```
UPDATE formulario
SET fecha = 'fecha a introducir'
WHERE id_proceso = 'id_del_proceso_obtenido'.
```

Tal y como mencionas en tu respuesta, lo que quieres es actualizar el id_proceso de la tabla formulario en base a la tabla propietario_procesos. Como no tengo mas información, te pongo un ejemplo:

- Actualizar el id_proceso del formulario que tenga id=8, con el valor del id_proceso del propietario con nombre "Zito".

  `UPDATE Formularios
  SET id_proceso = ( SELECT id_proceso 
                     FROM propietario_procesos
                     WHERE nombre_propietario = "Zito")
  WHERE id=8;`

Comment: Perdona, me había confundido, el "id_propietario no existe".. id_proceso=3 . Esta actualizado. Si, lo que necesito hacer es actualizar una fila en la tabla formulario, tiene que actualizar el id_proceso (el valor se coge de la tabla "propietario_procesos") where id = "$id" . Gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, con los ejemplos faciltiados, te debería valer para operar entre las dos tablas.

Comment: Vale! Muchísimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas soy algo nuevo disculpa si tengo algún error, yo haría algo así mira.

```
    UPDATE tbl_formulario
    SET    tbl_formulario.colum1 = ''
    FROM   tbl_formulario INNER JOIN tbl_propietario 
    ON     tbl_formulario.id = tbl_propietario.id_proceso
    WHERE  tbl_formulario.id_proceso = tbl_propietario.id_proceso
```

Espero haber entendido y explicarme bien, si no es así lo siento estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: No funciona... Muchas gracias aún así